# Should we re-run pg_prewarm('table') after data changes?

Tags: postgresql

As explained in the title, should we re-run `pg_prewarm('table')` after any `insert` / `update` / `delete` to the `table`?

Comment: Does it solve a problem for you? If so, what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Given that

> any insert / update / delete to the table

already passes through all the possible caches, reloading them again into the same caches is likely unnecessary.

Pre-warming is something you *might* consider doing upon a cold start, but doing so on a system that's already active might be counter-productive.